# Awk - Syntax error

Tags: linux, unix

I am writing a bash script.

```
setenv lineNUM `grep -n ms-listviewtable wget_list.log | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d ':' -f 1`
setenv next `expr $lineNUM + 2`
echo `awk '{FNR>=$lineNUM && FNR<=$next}' wget_list.log`
```

It returns me with the following syntax error.

```
awk: {FNR>=$lineNUM && FNR<=$next}
awk: ^ syntax error
```

Anything wrong here?

Comment: There are a number of things wrong there. 1) `setenv` is not part of bash, so you are using some shell other than bash, maybe csh. 2) An `awk` statement is generally of the form `/pattern/{action}`. You are putting your pattern within the braces of the action part. 3) `Awk` doesn't know about environment variables, so you'll have to surround your awk program with " instead of ' and let the shell expand those variables, or use some other method to get those values into your `awk` program. 4) You don't need the last echo. The `awk` command without the surrounding \`s will print the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a condition, but no action in your awk program. Try this:

```
awk '{if(FNR>=ENVIRON["lineNUM"] && FNR<=ENVIRON["next"]) print $0}' wget_list.log
```

Or just:

```
head $next | tail -n +$lineNUM wget_list.log
```

[Print a file skipping first lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604864/print-a-file-skipping-x-lines-in-bash)

Comment: @user2052801 I'm glad we could help. Voting and accepting answers is a great way to give thanks too.

Comment: @Bailevs - I can only accept as i cannot vote because of the reputation lacking.